# Passing an object method by reference to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, javascript-objects

So I've been trying to get this callback working inside of an object and I was just wondering if:

1) it's possible,
   2) special syntax is required.

So instead of just having a regularly declared function:

```
function callback() {}
```

And passing that to another function by reference:

doSomething(callback)

Im trying to pass an object property that contains a function:

```
   {
     prop: function() {}
   }
```

and send that as a call back.

The problem is, passing the reference of prop throws an error:

```
doSomething(prop):
```

throws: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

If a complete example is needed, let me know.

Thanks,
Ken

** Edit **

Okay so after some confusion I'm typing a fairly complete example.

```
var obj = {
    init: function() {
        this.some_function(this.callback_function)
    },
    some_function: function(callback) {
      callback();
    },
    callback_function: function() {
      // Callback!
    }
}
```

This is throwing the unexpected token error unless I put the () when I pass this.callback_function as an argument to some_function().

Thanks and sorry for not posting a fuller-example earlier.

Ken

Comment: "This is throwing the unexpected token error": No, [it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/xbgSQ/). Just keep in mind that the `this` keyword does *not* refer to `obj` when `obj.callback_function` is called.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this is not the solution to the OP's question but I google for "passing object methods as call backs" and this came up. I also found a link http://bitstructures.com/2007/11/javascript-method-callbacks.html which helped me understand how to do it in js. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Though I solved this long ago, it's nice to know the community is a very helpful one.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the method:

```
var obj = {
    prop: function() {}
};
doSomething(obj.prop);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll post a full example in a bit - but this is what I am currently doing. Throws unexpected token error unless you include the () with the argument.

Comment: @Ken I'm still waiting for your example. I'm not sure I got you question, but I'm afraid that your actual problem is Javascript syntax.

Comment: sorry for taking so long, I'm on a family vacation and was shuttled out the door immediately after posting this.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `obj.func` as an argument, it passes the function losing `this` from the scope.

```
some_function: function(callback) {
    callback.call(this);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mistyping the semicolon at the end of `doSomething(prop):`

Comment: Sorry - I typed that from my phone. Typing a full example now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response ( I was on vacation ), It was a syntax error, I forgot a comma delimiter in my object method.